# Sharing logic in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've used higher order component to share a function between my components.With this implementation,the function comes as a prop in my component.
The app supports multi languages so in each component a key is passed and the hash value is obtained to display. Hash values are passed to all the components using the context. Now `getSkinHash` access the context and returns the hash value.

```
const {getSkinHash} = this.props; //shared function,accesses the context

const value = getSkinHash(SOME_VALUE);
```

No problem with this implementation but getting the function out of prop every time leads to writing lot's of boilerplate code in all the components.

Is there a better/alternate ways to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that there's no better way to do this, although it would be pretty cool, cause I also need it.

Comment: I'm not sure how much it reduces boilerplate but perhaps another option would be to call the function in `mapStateToProps` and pass the result instead?

Comment: @TomFenech in my case every component pass a value and gets the hash, so that implementation doesn't suit my case. Thanks

Comment: Hmm I think that in order for anyone to come up with an improvement (or perhaps just to tell you that no such thing exists) we would have to know a bit more about your use case. Maybe you should [edit] to show us a bit more.

Comment: @TomFenech edited, added the scenario in my app

Answer (score 0):

React works with properties, so you can't just say you don't want to work with properties. That is when sharing data between components.

As far as you can do to shorten

```
const {getSkinHash} = this.props;
const value = getSkinHash(SOME_VALUE);
```

is to:

`this.props.getSkinHash(SOME_VALUE)`.

If that is a generic function, not component dependent, you can choose to import it into your component just like you import other stuff.

```
import { myFunction } from './functions'
```

Then you would simple call it with `myFunction`.

If you need your function to synchronize data between your components, use a [Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/) action and connect your components to the global state. Your other components will get to know value hash changes too.